# JavaScript: function return closest value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the value of the closest object to my position in a function.

I tried to put the entities in a array and than I tried return closest object to my position with a for loop, but it did not work. How can I do this?

```
function getMyEntity() {
  return Game.currentGame.world.localPlayer.entity.getFromTick();
}

function getOtherEntity() {
  var MyPlayerEntity = getMyEntity();

  var entities = Game.currentGame.world.entities;
  for (var uid in entities) {
    // how i get closest entity to my player entity here?
    var gameObject = entities[uid].fromTick;

    console.log(entities[uid].fromTick.position, MyPlayerEntity.position)
    if (gameObject.entityClass == "Prop" && gameObject.uid !== MyPlayerEntity.uid) {
      return gameObject;
    }
  }
}

function aimAssist() {
  var MyPlayerEntity = getMyEntity();
  var OtherEntity = getOtherEntity();
  if (OtherEntity == undefined) return

  var aimPosition = {
    x: OtherEntity.position.x - MyPlayerEntity.position.x,
    y: OtherEntity.position.y - MyPlayerEntity.position.y
  }
  return aimPosition;
}
```

Comment: Can you define 'closest'?

Comment: He means closest in terms of distance I think, according to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a bad advice, for now it'll work, as your game grows it will be bad because of O(n^2) complexity. Read a bit about quadtrees and see if you can do that. Meanwhile you can compare the euclidean distance, do not need to take the square root:

```
Object.keys(entities)
.map(function(d,i){
  var dx = entities[d].fromTick.position.x - MyPlayerEntity.position.x, 
       dy = entities[d].fromTick.position.y - MyPlayerEntity.position.y,
       result = {D:(dx * dx) + (dy + dy), obj:entities[d] , valueOf: function(){return this.D};
  return result;
}).sort(function(a,b){
    return a-b;
})[0].obj; //this returns the closest one
```

So your original function becomes  this:

```
function getOtherEntity() {
  var MyPlayerEntity = getMyEntity();

  var entities = Game.currentGame.world.entities;
  return Object.keys(entities)
    .map(function(d,i){
      var dx = entities[d].fromTick.position.x - MyPlayerEntity.position.x, 
           dy = entities[d].fromTick.position.y - MyPlayerEntity.position.y,
           result = {D:(dx * dx) + (dy + dy), obj:entities[d] , valueOf: function(){return this.D};
      return result;
    }).sort(function(a,b){
        return a-b;
    })[0].obj; //this returns the closest one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an array of objects which contain the Object-ID and distance, and sort it by distance. 
The first array-item is the closest to the player.

The array may look like 
`[{uid: 1234, distance: 12}, {uid: 1235, distance: 16}, ...]`

You can sort arrays with `arrayName.sort(sortingFunction)`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can get x and y coordinates from `gameObject.position` and `MyPlayerEntity.position` you could use a bit of Pitagoras: c^2 = a^2 +b^2, with c being the distance

```
let a = gameObject.position.x - MyPlayerEntity.position.x;
let b = gameObject.position.y - MyPlayerEntity.position.y;
let distanceSquared = a*a + b*b;
```

Since you don't seem to need the exact distance and `sqrt()` is expensive, you can use the value in `distanceSquared` and other variables declared outside of the loop to keep track

```
let closestDistance;
let closest;
```

to make the proper comparisons

```
if(distanceSquared < closestDistance){
    closestDistance = distanceSquared;
    closest = gameObject;
}
```

After you loop through the array, the closest entity reference should be:

```
return closest;
```